# Find index page name from its directory name in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a static site with a setup like:

```
location / { index index.html; }
location /about/ { index about.html; }
location /app/ { index app.html; }
location /app/support/ { index support.html; }
```

This approach will not scale but I would like to continue this naming practice for the index files.

How to write a common case to resolve wrapping directory's names into index files with the same names? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use index.html in all directories?

Comment: @AlexanderT It's more convenient for working with them – ten "index.html" tabs in a text editor are slightly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `try_files` instead of an `index` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more. For example:

```
location ~ ^(.*)/([^/]+)/$ {
    try_files $1/$2/$2.html =404;
}
```

Placement of regular expression `location` blocks is critical as they are evaluated in order. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.